# Shoulda matcher `validate_length_of` in RSpec with Reform form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda, reform

I'm setting up specs for my forms (using `Reform` gem) with `RSpec` and `Shoulda Matchers` gems. I'cant figure out why I'm having validation issues.

My actual configurations :

```rb
  ruby '2.5.1'
  gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'reform-rails', '~> 0.1'
```

I've already tried different sorts of length validations in my form. But nothing make things much better.

Here is the minimal form used for testing :

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class UserForm < Reform::Form
  # == Properties  ==========================================================
  property :nickname


  # == Validations ==========================================================
  validates :nickname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 100 } 
end
```

Here is the spec :

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

RSpec.describe UserForm, type: :model do
  subject { described_class.new(User.new) }

  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :nickname }
  it { is_expected.to validate_length_of(:nickname).is_at_least(3).is_at_most(100) }
end
```

Note that the `validate_presence_of` matcher works perfectly.

I'm having as `RSpec` output :

```
  1) UserForm should validate that the length of :nickname is between 3 and 100
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_length_of(:nickname).is_at_least(3).is_at_most(100) }

       Expected UserForm to validate that the length of :nickname is between
       3 and 100, but this could not be proved.
         After setting :nickname to ‹"xxx"›, the matcher expected the
         UserForm to be valid, but it was invalid instead, producing these
         validation errors:

         * nickname: ["is too short (at least 3 characters)"]
```

I'm obviously excepting to make these sorts of validations working.

I hope I can find help here :)

Comment: Is there any other method that runs as a `before_validation` callback which affects the length of the `nickname` field? Could you please share the callback-related code, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reform is known not to work with shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/934). Basically, all of the model matchers in shoulda-matchers work by:

- Making a new instance of the class under test.
- Setting attributes on that instance.
- Calling `validate` on that instance.
- Reading any possible validation errors from `errors`.

However, [Reform doesn't work this way](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform/issues/156#issuecomment-226122901); you don't set properties on the form object individually and then call `valid?`, you call `validate` with the properties you want to set on the form object, and then those properties are validated in the process of being set. So that's likely why you're getting this error — because shoulda-matchers is trying to manually set the properties, and then `validate` is blowing them away.

Unfortunately, there's not a way to get shoulda-matchers to work with Reform without writing some kind of adapter. We don't plan on adding this to the gem any time soon but we will take a PR! Other than this, apparently [the Reform team was talking about making some RSpec matchers](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform/issues/414) in the spirit of shoulda-matchers, but I'm not sure how much progress has been made there, if any.

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful :/